# Error uploading Enhanced Notes - Invalid ShareType

Tags: data-loader, notes, richtext-notes

I have migrated Notes to Enhanced Notes (ContentNote) using SF data loader. Most of the records are migrated successfully, only in few of the records I am receiving this error

> Invalid sharing type "I"

I tried changing the ShareType to 'C' (Collaborator) but same error. Does it have something to do with security settings of the Parent (LinkedEntityId) record? All the error records have ParentIds in Quote ('0Q0') or Email Template ('00X') objects.

Comment: Do you see any difference in terms of ownership/ Parents in the records that got migrated vs. those that failed?

Comment: I do not see any visible difference.

Comment: How did you resolve the ShareType 'C' issue? Solutions/Suggestions will be helpful